# Button action for a specific list item in Fyne

Tags: go, fyne

I have a list in the GUI which has a simple string slice as its data source. And for every list item I create a button that should do something for that specific list item.

Here is some example code:

```golang
var data = []string{"folder1", "folder2"}

...

func someListCreationMethod(data []string) *widget.List {
    return widget.NewList(
        func() int {
            return len(data)
        },
        func() fyne.CanvasObject {
            return container.NewPadded(
                widget.NewLabel("Will be replaced"),
                widget.NewButton("Do Something", nil),
            )
        },
        func(id widget.ListItemID, item fyne.CanvasObject) {
            item.(*fyne.Container).Objects[1].(*widget.Label).SetText(data[id])
        },

    )
}
```

How can I wire up the button to the list item? I need a way to know which exact button was pressed or a way that the button knows on which list item it sits (or which list item is his parent).

Is there a way to do this?

Maybe `widget.NewListWithData()` is something that would address this issue but I'm unsure if this will help in this case.

**Edit:** Here is a more graphical example to show this (the code for this is slightly different but the principles are the same as with the code above):
[image]

In this case I want to execute the pull for the one repo which the "pull" button belongs to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the button function by assigning `Button.OnTapped`

Comment: Thank you, but if I have a list of say 4 items, how do I make sure that each button knows which list item it is assigned to, so that the action it performs only works on the one list item. I'll try to add a visual explanation later in the question.

Comment: In the same way that calling `SetText` is showing the right data… pass it into a function you set to the button.

Like `b.OnTapped = func() { doSomething(id) }`

Comment: Thank you! That pointed me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

Credit goes to [@andy.xyz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/672958/andy-xyz) as he pointed me in the right direction.

I just want to provide some example code if people are searching for a solution.

```golang
func someListCreationMethod(data []string) *widget.List {
    return widget.NewList(
        func() int {
            return len(data)
        },
        func() fyne.CanvasObject {
            return container.NewPadded(
                widget.NewLabel("Will be replaced"),
                widget.NewButton("Do Something", nil),
            )
        },
        func(id widget.ListItemID, item fyne.CanvasObject) {
            item.(*fyne.Container).Objects[0].(*widget.Label).SetText(data[id])

            // new part
            item.(*fyne.Container).Objects[1].(*widget.Button).OnTapped = func() {
                fmt.Println("I am button " + data[id])
            }
        },

    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am crazy enough to try to learn Go and Fyne both at the same time, so there may be a better solution. I found this code worked to click on a playing card in a displayed set, and return which one was tapped. The button background is transparent:

```
    gridHuman := container.NewGridWithColumns(11)
    var cardHuman [10]fyne.Widget
    var cardBoxHuman [10]*fyne.Container

    for idx, item := range human.hand {
        pic := canvas.NewImageFromResource(cards.cardArt[item])
        pic.SetMinSize(fyne.NewSize(60, 90))
        cardHuman[idx] = widget.NewButton("", func() { testme(idx) })
        cardBoxHuman[idx] = container.NewStack(pic, cardHuman[idx])
        gridHuman.Add(cardBoxHuman[idx])
    }

    func testme(idx int) {
        fmt.Println(idx)
    }
```